# How can I aggregate over the best rated words?

Tags: r

I have followed structure:

```
   rating               words
1:    5.0 sushi, steak, fries
2:    5.0  sushi, fries, wine
3:    4.5         steak, wine
4:    4.5               steak
5:    3.5        salad, bread
6:    3.0         rice, bread
```

I want to get the best rated words and order them in a ranking with probably the mean of the rating, like followed:

```
   rank  words
1:    1  sushi, fries
2:    2  wine
3:    3  steak
4:    4  salad
5:    5  bread
6:    6  rice
```

Code for reproduction:

```
rating <- c(5.0,5.0,4.5,4.5,3.5,3.0)
words <- c("sushi, steak, fries","sushi, fries, wine","steak, wine","steak",
           "salad, bread","rice, bread")
dt <- data.table(rating,words)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `data.table`, we can split the 'words', `unlist` the column, while `rep`licate the 'rating' based on the `lengths`, get the `mean` of 'rating' by 'words', `paste` the 'words', by the `rank` and then `order` the 'rank'

```
library(data.table)
dt[, words := strsplit(words, ",\\s+")]
dt[, .(rating = rep(rating, lengths(words)), 
   words = unlist(words))][, mean(rating), words][,
    .(words = toString(words)), .(rank = frank(-V1,
        ties.method = "dense"))][order(rank)]
```

-output

```
   rank        words
1:    1 sushi, fries
2:    2         wine
3:    3        steak
4:    4        salad
5:    5        bread
6:    6         rice
```

---

The `tidyverse` equivalent of the above code would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt %>% 
 separate_rows(words) %>% 
 group_by(words) %>% 
 summarise(rating = mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
 group_by(rating = dense_rank(-rating)) %>% 
 summarise(words = toString(words))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  rating words       
   <int> <chr>       
1      1 fries, sushi
2      2 wine        
3      3 steak       
4      4 salad       
5      5 bread       
6      6 rice
```